# gdalwarp cutline creates artefacts not quite no data

Tags: gdal

I am trying to clip an imagery tile by a shapefile using gdalwarp.

[image]

I have tried a number of different commands...

`gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline Coast.shp IN.JPG OUT.tif`

`gdalwarp -of GTiff -dstnodata -cutline Coast.shp -crop_to_cutline IN.JPG OUT.tif`

However both gdalwarp commands result in some pixels that are not nodata.

[image]

I do not think I can use -srcnodata  -dstnodata  because the water is different RGB values so cannot specify a correct value.

How can I clip without these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6986 provides further details around this issue.

It suggests the following as a potential resolution... "This seems specific to jpeg-in-tiff compression, as using COMPRESS=DEFLATE doesn't show the same issue".